# What are the restrictions on using substitution in integration?

Tags: integration, continuity, substitution

What are the restrictions on using substitution in integration?

For example, integration in this case may be done by the substitution $u=\tan x$, as seen in the following $\textit{Mathematica}$ notebook

[image]

Integration done by substitution $u=\tan {x\over 2}$.

[image]

The source function is a **continuous positive** function over $\mathbb {R}$ which implied by necessity that its antiderivative is **continuous** and **increasing** over $\mathbb {R}$ (which contradicts the graph of its analytical antiderivative that has jumb discontinuities).

When I sent this question to Dr.Math, he replied - thanks to him - that the antiderivative of the function $ f(x)={1\over {1+{\sin x}^2}} $ is:

$$ {\tan^{-1} (\sqrt 2 \tan x) \over \sqrt 2}  + \lfloor \frac x \pi-\frac 12 \rfloor * \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} + C $$

Which matches the "True" antiderivative of the function after redefining the integral at $( {\pi \over 2} + n.\pi) $. 
The second term has a derivative of $0$ over $ \Bbb R $.

This kind of "weird" functions makes me wonder about the "Restrictions" on using substitution when evaluating integrals, how to know that the function I work on needs refinements, and how to construct this "True" antiderivative ?

Comment: This site is not designed for "open discussion"---perhaps you could replace that statement with a concrete question?

Comment: statement removed

Comment: David J. Jeffreys has written several articles about this. Try googling "The importance of being continuous", for example.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you very much, I googled and found this paper and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome!