# Problem with calculation this integral: $\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}$

Tags: integration

**Question**

Calculate this integral: $$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}$$

---

**Solution**

$$I=\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}=\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{\cos^2x+4\sin^2x}=\displaystyle\int \frac{\sec^2x\;dx}{1+4\tan^2x}$$ Let's apply substitution $u=2\tan x$, so $du=2\sec^2x\;dx$  $$I=\dfrac12\displaystyle\int \frac{du}{1+u^2}=\frac12\arctan(u)+c=\frac12\arctan(2\tan x)+c$$ In this case; $$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}=\left[\frac12\arctan(2\tan x)\right]_{x=0}^{x=\pi}=0$$.

---

But we know that: $$\frac{1}{1+3\sin^2 x} \ge \frac14$$ Therefore; $$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x} \ge \displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{4}=\frac{\pi}4$$ On the other hand; $$0 \ge \frac{\pi}4$$ which is not true.

1) Where is the problem? (Why?)
2) How we can correct this mistake by applying the same substitution?

Comment: Please no `\displaystyle` in titles.

Comment: I think the idea of @Brightsun is the way to go here, so I do not post an answer. Just a comment: It has been discussed before on this site (I'm unable to find the link, sorry) that one can find primitive functions working for all $x$. In this case, one such primitive is given by $$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\cos x\sin x}{1+\sin^2x}\Bigr).$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356523/what-are-the-restrictions-on-using-substitution-in-integration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue becomes evident once we look into the graph of the actual antiderivative and the answer you found:

$\hspace{7em}$[image]

The red line is your answer $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\arctan(2\tan x)$ while the gray dashed-line is the actual integral $x \mapsto \int_{0}^{x} d\theta/(1+3\sin^2\theta)$.

This discrepancy can be tracked down to the fact that your substitution $u = \tan\theta$ has discontinuity at $\theta = \pi/2$. In particular, $\tan\theta$ is not differentiable at $\theta = \pi/2$. Since the antiderivative technique is the reverse process of differentiation and differentiation fails at discontinuity, it is not surprising that anti-differentiation often fails at discontinuity.

There are some workarounds for this issue.

**Reducing.** One way is to manipulate your integral so that your substitution no longer suffers from this issue. Various symmetries can be exploited for this task. For instance, you can write
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta} = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta} $$
and apply the substitution $u = \tan\theta$ to any of the last 2 integrals.

**Gluing.** Although your substitution does not work on all of $[0, \pi]$, it does work on each subintervals $[0,\pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2, \pi]$. So your answer remains valid on each of these intervals. This suggests that
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\frac{d\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2\tan x) + C_1, & x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \\
\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2\tan x) + C_2, & x \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]
\end{cases} $$
Since the LHS is continuous on $[0,\pi]$, you can determine $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that the right-hand is also continuous at $x = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that $\tan{x}$ is not continuous at $x=\pi/2$, so the derivative doesn't exist and you can't substitute on this interval. There are several ways around this:

1. Drawing the graph of $\tan{x}$ on $(0,\pi)$, we see it is initially positive, has a vertical asymptote at $x=\pi/2$, then returns from being very negative to $0$ at $x=\pi$. Therefore the substitution will work fine on $(0,\pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2,\pi)$ separately. This gives you
   $$ \left[ \frac{1}{2}\arctan{2\tan{x}} \right]_{0}^{\pi/2} + \left[ \frac{1}{2}\arctan{2\tan{x}} \right]_{-\pi/2}^{0} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{y \to \infty}\arctan{y} - \arctan{0} +\arctan{0}- \lim_{y \to -\infty}\arctan{y}  \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
2. $\sin{(\pi-x)} = \sin{x}$, so the integral is double the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and as we noted, the substitution has no problem there.
3. Use $t=\tan{\frac{1}{2}x}$. This will work since $t$ depends continuously on $x$. (This does give a nastier rational function, though.)
4. Similar to 2., but shift the interval of integration to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Again, $\tan{x}$ is continuous on here, and we notice the calculation gives the same answer as 1.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: write
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}.
$$
Then, the substitution you suggest is legitimate because $\tan x$ is monotone on $(0,\pi/2)$.