# Undefined substitution while integrating - complex integral

Tags: integration

Take a look at the integral - $\int \frac{1}{1+\sin^2x}$.
The integrand is defined for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$\\$
most solutions use the substitution $t = \tan(x)$.
$\\$

my question is what about $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi \cdot k$ ?
$\\$

the substituion is not defined, and the solution is not defined in these points.

Comment: See comments and linked questions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356523/what-are-the-restrictions-on-using-substitution-in-integration

Comment: the substitution can be applied just in the regions where the integrand is well-defined. However, in the critical points, we can understand the integral as improper