# Does $a_1\sqrt{1}+a_2\sqrt{2}+...+a_n\sqrt{n}=0$ have no solutions over the rationals?

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers

I had recently met a question that asked to show that $a\sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3}+c=0$ has no solutions over the rationals (except for $0$) for $a,b$ and $c$. To show this I moved $c$ to the other side then squared both sides. Then the equation re-arranges into $\sqrt{6}=\frac{c^2-2a^2-3b^2}{2ab}$, which is a contradiction as one side is irrational and the other side is rational. I was wondering if I could extend this to $n$ terms, i.e does $a_1\sqrt{1}+a_2\sqrt{2}+...+a_n\sqrt{n}=0$ have any rational solutions for any $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and how would I prove that if it did? This time I can't just square both sides because there are too many terms to isolate so I was wondering if anyone could help (dis)prove this statement that would be great.

Comment: $2\times \sqrt 1 -\sqrt 4 = 0$.

Comment: @lulu What if I excluded all perfect squares from $n$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30687/42969 for a general statement.

Comment: @Quippy, you have to exclude numbers with a nontrivial square factor.

Comment: $2\sqrt 3 - \sqrt {12}=0$.  Study the case of primes, as proposed by @MartinR.

Comment: @MartinR I haven't learnt linear algebra so I can't understand anything in that link, if $a_1..a_n$ were all primes, would there be a more elementary proof?

Comment: I think that the proofs of the more general cases require a bit of theory of extension fields. At the very least, those pieces of theory make the arguments simpler. Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442265/11619). Sorry about advertising my own proof. Field theory makes it more transparent why square roots of square-free integers are linearly independent (you don't need them to be primes).

Comment: It may be better to check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619). It implies that the square roots of all the square-free integers are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$. The reason is that those square roots all live in a suitable extension field of the prescribed type. The argument in my answer in another linked question requires Galois theory, which is one level deeper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\left(\mathbb Q[\sqrt p_1,\dots,\sqrt p_n]:\mathbb Q\right)=2^n$ for distinct primes $p_i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f). If you ask a question on rational solutions to equations then usually an answer without abstract or linear algebra, or even without number theory cannot be expected.

Comment: Since you know already much about [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416083/why-does-displaystyle-int-pi-pi-frac-sec2x2-tan2x1-dx-evalu) I wonder why you say you haven't learned linear algebra?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the notation has completely gone over my head, could you put into simple words what  $\left(\mathbb Q[\sqrt p_1,\dots,\sqrt p_n]:\mathbb Q\right)=2^n$ means. I've never studied set theory so I don't know where to start to understand your answer. COuld you just explain really briefly what some of the notation means so I can research it in my own time?